# Deploying Spring MVC web app on heroku

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, heroku

I have problem with deploying my app on Heroku.
Locally, everything works fine.
I've added PostgreSQL to my heroku app, change configuration from mysql to posgresql in my yaml file and pushed app to heroku repository.

Logs I receive:
[Log](https://gist.github.com/Gromo13/c912bec77c5ca54e61fb6b40862e0bb9)

Entire app repository is available on my git hub page:
[Repository page, postgresql version branch](https://github.com/Gromo13/personalBlog/tree/heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try build your app using maven to target: `mvn clean install`

The first step if you havent installed heroku cli in heroku your server:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
```

Next deploy application using command from target folder:

```
heroku deploy:war app_name.war --app name_app_in_heroku
```

where `name_app_in_heroku` is application name in heroku

Comment: I receive
` !    deploy:war is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant destroy
 !    Run heroku help for a list of available topics.
`
error. Actually I am useing windows with installed Heroku CLI. Maybe that's reason for this.

Comment: I've created `.war` file but I am unable to use this command. I think it do not exist in Heroku CLi on Windows.

Comment: @Gromo I edited my answer and befeore deoply invoke this: `heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy`

Comment: @Abihabi97 I deployed `.war` file but it do not work yet.
I receide 404 with no errors in log. There was only one mention on deploying, taht I do not have `web.xml` file. Which I won't have because I am using annotation absed configuration and Spring Boot.

Comment: @Abihabi97 When I was looking for problems in logs (when my app was deployed using simple push to heroku) I found that my app had problem with `INSERT INTO posts (title, user_id, date, contents) VALUES ('First Post', 1, CURRENT_TIME(), 'Welcome to my personal blog. You are reading first post on this site.' );` this line of come from my `data.sql` file. There was problem with one of `)`. I do not knwo whyu, on my local MySQL database everything works fine. I commented out this line and every line next to it, so I will see if this was causing crash. It's odd, but I have to wait for dynos reset.

Comment: To see if it helped.

Comment: @Gromo have you installed mysql in heroku ?

Comment: Heroku have MySQL support? I've added Heroku PostgreSQL and refactor my configuration to use PostgreSQL.

Comment: did you changed configuration to heroku connection properties instead localhost ?

Comment: @Abuhabi87
Of course. I am using `${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}` to set datasource url, `${DATABASE_USERNAME}` to set datasource username and `${DATABASE_PASSWORD}` for password.

Comment: @Abuhabi87 I deployed my app, I had to remove brackets in insert querries. Now my app cannot her /fragments/head template and I receive HTTP 500 errors.

Comment: @Abuhabi87
After deplloyment I am receiving `Error resolving template "/fragments/head.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (home:4)` error. Locally everything works fine. Heroku do not see my templates